# Should Dart be inferencing class member types?

Tags: dart, type-inference

In Dart 2.6.0, when I use `is` to test the type of a class member variable, the conditional code block does not inference the type.

In the following code, the method `show1()` produces the error, "The getter 's2' isn't defined for the class 'C1'." Meanwhile, the method `show2()` compiles just fine.

```dart
class C1 {
  C1(this.s1);
  String s1;
}

class C2 extends C1 {
  C2(String s1, this.s2) : super(s1);
  String s2;
}

class InferenceTest {
  InferenceTest(this.c);
  C1 c;

  void show1() {
    print(c.s1);
    if (c is C2) print(c.s2); // error
  }

  void show2(C1 c) {
    print(c.s1);
    if (c is C2) print(c.s2); // no error
  }
}
```

This seems like a bug, but it also seems like I shouldn't be the first to notice this. I encountered the problem trying to use inferencing on `widget.myValue` from a widget State.

Have I found a bug, or is there something I'm not understanding?

(I'd find this reasonable in a multi-threaded environment like Java, because the value of `c` could change between the `is` test and the use of `c`. But I understand that Dart largely assumes a single thread.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart does not type-promote instance variables, only local variables.

When you test that a local variable has a specific type, then the program can use the variable as if it had the tested type ... with some caveats because the language needs to be absolutely sure that the value doesn't change between the test and the use. For example, there must be no assignments to the variable in the scope guarded by the test, and there must be no assignments to the variable captured in a closure. Because the variable is local, the compiler can assure itself that this is sufficient to ensure that the variable value doesn't change.

The instance variable `c` of the class `InferenceTest` has type `C1`. There are valid programs where the value of `c` can change between the test `c is C2` and the use `c.s2`, and it can be changed by code in a completely different library, so the language does not dare to do type promotion in that case. Therefore the type of `c` is still `C1` at the `c.s2` access, and you can't access `s2`.

If you want the promotion, try moving the value into a local variable:

```
var c = this.c;
if (c is C2) print(c.s2);
```

This works, which is also what you see in your `show2` method because function parameters are local variables and therefore subject to type promotion.

Comment: Thank you! I see how a closure somewhere else could change the value of `c` from a different thread. Did you mean to suggest another way my example code might change with the words, "there must be no assignments to the variable in the scope guarded by the test"?

Comment: An instance variable can be changed from any place that has access to the object, and Dart does not try to figure out where that may be. There might not be any, but that's not detectable locally when compiling this one function. So, the compiler simply refuses to promote instance variables on general principle. The extra rules I mention only apply to local variables, because not even all of those can safely be promoted.